# Insert employee data into a database

Tags: php, html, sql

I've constructed code using prepared statements to try and avoid chances of SQL injections. This code is meant to insert the employees information. It does what I need it to do but I want to know if the php or html used in this is suitable for a proper application or if its vulnerable.

```
    <form name="register" action="" method="post">
 
        
            <label for = "fname"> <b>First name</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" size="48"> 

            <label for = "lname"> <b>Last name</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" size="48"> 

            <label for = "dob"> <b>Date of birth</b> </label>
            <input type="date" name="dob" size="48">   

            <label for = "address"> <b>Address</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="address" size="48"> 

            <label for = "position"> <b>Position</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="position" size="48"> 

            <label for = "email"> <b>Email</b> </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="48">

            <label for = "password"> <b>Password</b> </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" size="48"> 

            <button type="submit" name="submit1"> Register a new administrator</button>
            <button type="submit" name="submit2"> Register a new employee</button>
           
            
        
    </form>
    
    </div>
    <?php
 include("dbcon.php");
 
 if(isset($_POST["submit1"]))
        
    { 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare ("insert into admin(Adminfnam,Adminlnam,DOB,Aemail,AAddress,APosition,Apassword) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); //Insert query to register a person
        $stmt ->bind_param("sssssss",$fname,$lname,$dob,$email,$address,$position,$password);
 
            $fname = $_POST["fname"];
            $lname = $_POST["lname"];
            $dob = $_POST["dob"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $address = $_POST["address"];
            $position = $_POST["position"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            $stmt-> execute();
        echo "Registered";

        $stmt-> close();
 
    }
```

Comment: Does this code actually work? It doesn't look like it does.

Comment: Yeps it does, i just want to know if this code is industry ready or if its vulnerable.@200_success

Comment: I was able to create a table using the column names listed in the `INSERT` query, then run the page on my local environment. I was able to submit the form and saw the output `Registered` and in the database I see a record corresponding to the values submitted in the form. @200_success what doesn't look like it would work?

Comment: Well i did try submitting a select * from employee statement into the first name field and nothing showed up, it jst got registered in the database so I assume that part of it worked @pacmaninbw

Comment: I don't think your code allows SQL-injection, but perhaps @pacmaninbw can explain how it still does? You can put `include("dbcon.php");` inside the `if` statement block, so you only connect to the database when you need it. You do not [sanitize the content of the form submission](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) so you may be vulnerable to [javascript injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) as already suggested. I think this code is too rudimentary, and incomplete, to warrant a proper review.

Comment: How does this code work, if the `bind_param()` call uses `$fname` *before* `$fname` is defined?

Comment: @200_success I wondered about that too... and while it may not mean it is acceptable to do so the [documentation even includes this practice in examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-examples). SO answers like [this one from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836724/1575353) and [this one from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961267/1575353) provides some explanation - it seems it is just a reference and then likely not used until the statement is executed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have removed the incorrect comment, you might want to alter your comment. I was more concerned about JavaScript.

Comment: @pacmaninbw: I can't alter the comment now, only delete it. I'll leave it, as it is, most people will just read over it.

Comment: This script does not work as designed because no data will be saved when `Register a new employee` is clicked. Also, `for` does not related to `name`-attributed elements.  There is no need for `<b>` tags, use label styling. You can directly bind elements from `$_POST` so there is no need to declare new single-use variables. You don't need to `close()` your statement -- PHP will do this for you. You should use all UPPERCASE when writing SQL keywords and functions for improved human readability.  Critically, you MUST NEVER store unencrypted password strings in your database (or anywhere).

Comment: Yes, the storing of a plain password is a critical error. Well spotted. Passwords should never be stored anywhere, not even encoded or encrypted. The only thing you should store is a [password hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) so a hacker, who somehow got access to your database, has a hard time reconstructing the password.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out the javascript injection vulnerability and the extra tips and references. I will improve my skills accordingly.  @KIKOSoftware

Answer (score 3):

This code is safe, working and on topic.

However, it fails to implement some very basic concepts which every server-side script must adhere to.

- passwords must be hashed using password_hash()
- The [HTTP standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616) requires a script that processed a POST request to do a redirect using GET method, to avoid duplicate records if a user will reload the page.

  - Therefore no such messages as "Registered" should be shown. In case you definitely need one, it has to be done via flash messages
  - a `header("Location: ...");` followed by `exit;` must be added instead
  - given a header must be sent, the entire form processing code must be placed above any HTML output
- it will be a very good idea to add some input validation, at least if a user entered all required values or entered values follow a specific format,  such as email

There could be also some minor optimizations

- no need for `$stmt->close();` as PHP will close everything automatically
- no need to assign every post element to a distinct variable, you can bind $_POST["fname"] already
- it would be a very good idea to make your code readable, so one don't have to scroll to the right for a mile to read your code

  - you can always store SQL query in a dedicated variable and split it into several lines
  - for the long list of arguments, it is recommended to list them vertically

like,

```
//Insert query to register a person
$sql = "insert into admin(Adminfnam,Adminlnam,DOB,Aemail,AAddress,APosition,Apassword)
        values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(
    "sssssss",
    $_POST["fname"],
    ...
 );
```

Comment: When does PHP automatically close the statement? It seems like a sloppy bad practice to rely on automatic closure, especially as the application may grow more complex such that there may be multiple statements in flight, running in a PHP engine that may have long-lived processes.

Comment: This part of code will never grow

Comment: That seems like a silly justification to trim one line of code, though? In my mind, removing `$stmt->close()` makes the program worse.

Comment: "food idea" -> "good idea"

Comment: @200_success It's a sloppy bad practice to call unnecessary functions. If you don't have to call something because your logic doesn't require, then do not call it.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things you might do to improve your script and not to repeat what has already been said:

- some more validation of user input is required, notably the E-mail address which is critical as it is the only point of contact here
- the form has to provide **meaningful feedback** to the user in case errors are detected upon submitting the form. Likewise, if the registration was successful be explicit about it. Don't leave the user in doubt.
- in web-based systems it is customary to have a **username** field along with full name and surname of the user. How are people supposed to log in to your site?
- the username should be the **primary key** in your table
- thus, in case the form is submitted more than once, a **duplicate** entry should be rejected
- you'll probably want a **unique constraint** on the E-mail address as well. Or think about how you'll handle a situation where a domain name lapses, and is re-registered by another person who would create an account on your site using an E-mail address already claimed by another user. On very popular sites this is something that can happen once in a while.
- in a real life application, you'd send a **confirmation link** to the user as a way of ensuring that the E-mail address is correct and reachable.
- generally speaking, accounts that are not confirmed with a certain time frame should be purged (think of the spambots and the pranks). A cron job can take care of that so the maintenance is automated. So you'd want to add a couple of fields like registration datetime, random token to send in confirmation E-mail + a boolean confirmed/unconfirmed flag
- now you know the password must be hashed, in 2022 it is not acceptable to store passwords in plain text. But you should also enforce **minimum password complexity**, with some common sense. 1234 is not a safe password and hashing won't help much in case of a breach. Right now there is nothing that stops people from using silly passwords.
- although the script is very short, make it a habit of using **functions**. For example, your PHP code could fit inside a register_user function. Then you can better separate HTML and PHP code. Also, smaller files are easier to maintain (and your functions can be reused in other parts of your site).
- not sure why your input fields all have a length of 48, this is something I would rather tweak with CSS. Ditto for the labels. Better yet use a framework like Bootstrap or similar. Or write your own style sheet. It doesn't take a lot of code.
- add a maxlength property on your input fields to constrain user input, the maxlength should reflect the field size in your database. Eg if you have allocated 50 characters in your table for the first name, then do not accept more than that from the user.
- this can be bypassed by malicious attackers though, so the length should also be checked server-side
- so try to see what happens if you enter a very large value that exceed the field size in your table, what do you see in your current setup? A warning or an error? Your code may still be safe, but you could possibly end up with truncated data in your database.
- for a street address, you could use a textarea instead to permit multiline input (one line is not always enough)

If this form is put in production as-is, I'm afraid your database will quickly fill up with **garbage** - and data that is not reliable is useless. Currently it would even be difficult to clean the table manually because you are not making a difference between confirmed and unconfirmed accounts. The form blindly accepts anything. BTW consider adding another field for the last login datetime. That makes it possible to identify and eventually purge inactive accounts.

Some more aspects to consider:

- character set: does the HTML page have a character set defined (Unicode or other), and does it match that of your table? How does it handle accents for example? Test it.

Comment: Most points are valid but the whole username business is rather questionable. "How are people supposed to log in to your site?" By email that identifies them well. Look at the site you are currently logged in. "The username should be the primary key". Nope, [by no means it should be a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438920/can-you-use-username-as-unique-identifier-primary-key), and I wouldn't make it even unique.  Email is enough. Again, look at this very site. And given there is already first and last name, there is no need for the username at all.